# Kubernetes Secret override failing for pod env variables

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

- I deployed a k8s secret.
- I deployed a pod that uses the above secret.
- Now I wanted to change the secret data, so I updated my k8s secret.
- And restarted my pod., so that it reads new data.

I did things in the sequence mentioned above.

But still, my service inside the pod is reading old secret data.

Now, I have two doubts:

1. Can someone please explain why is this happening??
2. Do secrets override my env variables(if same), when do they exactly
   override, is it after the service comes up??

Comment: What are the specific commands you're running?  How does your Deployment spec get the Secret value?

Comment: Please share the manifests for your pod/deployment and secret and how how you are using the ENV variables in your application.

Comment: And you don't have to restart pods for secret changes to take affect, they are automatically sync-ed by the kubelet. (given you're using secrets as volumes).